# How can I combine 2 chains of code in RxAndroid2?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I need to request some data from shared preferences and do some checks update sharedpreferences 
and then return boolean I need to keep this in Computation thread.And if the the return is true I need to continue with the below code otherwise I need to call doSomething2()
My question is how should I combine these 2 part of code 
where the first part is `Flowable.just(isPayable())` which should be subscribed in Computation  thread  and based the return value continue with the existing solution

```
 .update(info)
 .observeOn(mMainThreadScheduler)
 .subscribe(() -> doSomething1{
           }),
          (Throwable throwable) -> doSomething2())
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use 
`Flow.just(isPayable())` - it might not be executed in computation scheduler.
either use 
`Flow.defer(()->Flow.just(isPayable()))` or

`Flow.fromCallable(() ->isPayable() )`

and in result:

```
Flow.fromCallable(() ->isPayable() )
.flatMap(value->
  if(value){ doSomething1() }else { doSomething2() }
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe({},{})
)
```

alternatively, if you do doSomething1() / doSomething2() do some UI stuff, you also can mark isPayable()== false as error, to do that:
Single.fromCallable(() ->isPayable() )
.map{ value-> if(value) return value else throw Exception("not payable") }
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe({ doSomething1()},{ doSomething2()})

Comment: Thanks @Lukas , I don't get you instead of just to use fromCallable() right ?

Comment: yes, because just() is hot observable and it emits immediately in current thread, regardless subscribeOn(..) call